# iPhone: 'Linking' between two sub-view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

Here's my view controller hierarchy:

```
| [A]
| ---- [A1]
| ---- [A2]
```

One accesses view controllers `A1` and `A2` by tapping `A1` and `A2` cells respectively within view controller `A`.

Say I have tapped through to `A1`, and within that view controller I press a button which brings me straight through to `A2`, how do I:

1. Remove `A1` as the visible view, and also relinquish it from memory.
2. Show `A2`.
3. Have it so that a back button appears on `A2`'s navigation controller which brings the user back to `A` when tapped.

As a bonus question, can anyone recall a native iPhone application which does this kind of thing? You know, just so I can see how Apple handles it.

Thanks friends.

Comment: People have asked about the relationship between `A1` and `A2`. Ideally I want them to interact as little as possible. I also don't want to couple `A1` and `A2` to `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use same presentModalView and dismissis methods just specify withAnimation: NO. This way path in navigation controller will be correct.

And I don't recall seeing anything like this in standard apps... which may be a sign for you to re-think why are you trying to do this.

Comment: Yep, I didn't think Apple apps did this. Thanks Sha.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the relationships between the controllers but basically you have to pop A1 from the `UINavigationController`'s stack and push A2 onto it.

Comment: This doesn't work. Popping a view controller means you can no longer push from it. And pushing first means the hierarcy ends up like this `A` -> `A1` -> `A2`.

Comment: You have to push from A. I don't see the problem here.